# How to check does EC2 Instance Savings Plan applied to my EC2 instance or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-savings-plans

I purchased EC2 Instance Savings Plan with full upfront.

Is is possible to check - does it applied to my EC2 instance or not? I want to be sure that I bought saving plan with correct settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to check it using [Utilization report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/latest/userguide/ce-sp-usingPR.html) and [coverage report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/latest/userguide/ce-sp-usingCR.html).